# SlideToggle div over content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 `div`s. In each div I have some content and also another div thats by default hidden and is relative positioned on top of the content. When I hover over the div I want the hidden div to slide up. What I tried isn't working for me.

code.. Ill just show part of it, since both divs are the same.
HTML:

```
<div class="youtube">
    <h1> Youtube </h1>
    <span></span>
    <div class="yt-desc">
     <p>
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et
        netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et
        netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
      </p>
    </div><!-- // .yt-desc -->  
  </div> <!-- // .youtube -->
```

CSS:

Heres the css for one,the `.forums` is exactly the same. I took out the unneeded css.

```
.youtube, .forums { background: #3c3c3c url(../images/boxes-bg.jpg) repeat-x;  float: left; position: relative; z-index: -1; width: 260px; }
.youtube h1, .forums h1 { text-indent: -9999px; margin: 26px auto; }
.youtube { margin: 0 216px 0 0; }
.youtube h1 { background: url(../images/yt-header.png) no-repeat; height: 36px; margin: 21px; auto; width: 212px; }
.youtube span { background: url(../images/icons/youtube.png) no-repeat; display: block; height: 75px; margin: 26px auto; width: 79px; }

.youtube .yt-desc, .forums .forums-desc {  position: absolute; top: 94px; left: 0px; padding: 5px; display: none; }
```

yt-desc is what i'm trying to get to slideup. But for some reason its not working.

Ive tried.

```
$(".youtube").hover(function () {
  $(".yt-desc").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Still no luck. Can anybody help? :/ Heres an idea of what i'm trying to get -
[image]

Comment: I think this is what I want, I tried it but it still didn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654829/jquery-mouse-over-div-slideup-and-mouse-out-div-slidedown

Comment: Are there javascript errors on the page?

Comment: Console on firebug says : Console says: missing formal parameter [Break on this error] function() { $(this).children(".yt-desc").show("fast"); },\n - and I also don't have any other javascript but that. Can it be the CSS?

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nhilae/btays/)

Using `display: none` doesn't render the element until you "show" it, so hiding away the element with `overflow: hidden` is probably better.

[Here is a nice tutorial on a similar effect](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/jquery-animations-a-7-step-program/)

Didn't solve your problem really, hope it helps anyway!

EDIT:
Your code with my example:

CSS

```
.youtube, .forums { background: #3c3c3c url(../images/boxes-bg.jpg) repeat-x; position: relative; width: 260px; overflow: hidden;}
.youtube h1, .forums h1 { text-indent: -9999px; margin: 26px auto; }

.youtube { margin: 0 216px 0 0; }
.youtube h1 { background: url(../images/yt-header.png) no-repeat; height: 36px; margin: 21px; auto; width: 212px; }
.youtube span { background: url(../images/icons/youtube.png) no-repeat; display: block; height: 75px; margin: 26px auto; width: 79px; }

.youtube .yt-desc, .forums .forums-desc {  width: 260px; position: absolute; bottom: -200px; padding: 5px;}
```

JQuery

```
$(".youtube").hover(  
    function(){            $(this).children("div.yt-desc").stop().animate({bottom: 0}, 500);  
    },  
    function(){              $(this).children("div.yt-desc").stop().animate({bottom: -20}, 500);  
});
```

Comment: Omnix: `z-index` messes with the hover-method from jquery - I guess you need to work around that.

Comment: Looks like Firefox doesn't like the `z-index:-1`, that's probably pushing it below `<body>` as far as Firefox's hover/click/... handling is concerned. On the up-side, the `z-index` setting isn't necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Some like this http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ENpsH/3/ should work; I stripped all the extraneous stuff out of your sample and started putting necessary bits back in. The basic idea is to position your sliding `<div>` way below the container then tuck it right up to the edge when you know how tall the container is; then, you can simply animate the `top` up and down on hover actions.

Comment: @omnix: It worked in Safari but Firefox didn't like the `z-index:-1`, I took the `z-index` out and Firefox is now happy with my updated example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".youtube").hover(
  function() { $(this).children(".yt-desc").show("fast"); },
  function() { $(this).children(".yt-desc").hide("fast"); }
);
```

This should work. I hope

Comment: Console says: missing formal parameter
[Break on this error] function() { $(this).children(".yt-desc").show("fast"); },\n

Comment: Hey mate, can I see the whole script in a page? Is it hosted somewhere I can access?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. On the CSS file line 43:

```
.youtube, .forums { background: #3c3c3c url(../images/boxes-bg.jpg) repeat-x; border: 1px solid #3c3c3c; border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -ms-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; float: left; position: relative; z-index: -1; width: 260px; }
```

Remove the Z-index: -1;

I fixed the javascript just to make it show up on the screen and now you need to fix the values:

```
  $(".youtube").hover(  
        function(){ 
            $(this).children(".yt-desc").show().animate({top: '+=50',});
        },  
        function(){ 
            $(this).children(".yt-desc").hide().animate({top: '-=50',});
        }
    );
```

Comment: This is perfect, but now yt-desc goes up[shows everything] then it goes down cutting half way.

Comment: As I said, you need to fix the animation.

Comment: What do you mean? I also messed around some, but when I do it, hover over it, the div just jumps in random places.

Comment: I also added {queue: false, duration:1000} to stop the slides from queue'in up.

Comment: Maybe I can give you the files? Its not a lot - A really simple page.